# Oracle Express dropping connections with 2 users

Tags: oracle10g

We are using Oracle Express as our development DB.  When 2 programmers try to connect to it via jdbc we get dropped connections.  Is this a limitation or Oracle Express edition?  If we have 2 separate logins we still have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no limitation in Oracle Express preventing two users to connect at the same time. In fact, I use as a quite alright production (more than 20 concurrent connections) database in some projects.

It might be something else.

If you want to check what is the number of sessions allowed in your database you can issue:

```
SELECT name, value 
  FROM v$parameter
 WHERE name = 'sessions'
```

Comment: I get 49 as the limit when I run this  query.  We have a very out of the box install of Oracle XE running on Windows 7 and when 2 users connect it definitely has some issues.  Any ideas?